# How to do "+=" in excel?

Tags: excel

I would like to use the old value of a cell to calculate its new value (hence, the equivalent of the '+=' operator in programming languages) while using excel solver.

How can I achieve that ? What do I have to write in the cell ?

Thanks.

EDIT : as it seems the question is not that clear, I will expand it. So here is a picture summarizing what I want to accomplish :

[image]

Now, imagine the objective of the excel solver is defined on the sum cell and the variable of the solver is x. The goal could be something like: find the maximum value of x so that the sum is inferior to an upper boundary.

X is incremented steadily and each time a new x is used, a new value f(x) has to be calculated.

The **sum** cell is the sum of the past value + the newly calculated f(x) i.e.

- first iteration: sum = f(0)
- second iteration: sum = f(0) + f(1),
- third iteration: sum = f(0) + f(1) + f(2) ; and so on.

I would like to know how to write the formula in the sum cell. I would preferably use only one cell for that purpose if possible. Hope this clarifies everything.

Comment: The simplest way is probably to create a new column with the old value plus the delta. You enter the formula on the first row, and then fill toward the end row. But I am no Excel expert, and there might be an "in-place" method.

Comment: Perhaps a sample data of before and after would help explain your problem better?

Comment: Is this when data is added into a cell? For example the cell has a 2 a 3 is entered so it now equals 5

Comment: If a formula overwrites the value of a cell, it will overwrite the formula contained in that cell.  You need to use another cell as your "variable". For an algorithm like this, you would probably be better off writing a custom function in VBA that you call in the cell's function.  That will keep you cell equations far more simple, and let you use a "real" language for the logic.

Answer (score 0):

`x += y` is the equivalent of `x=x+y` in VBA.

On the worksheet, if cell `A1` has a value of `2` and cell `B1`has a value of `3` then you could enter in `C1` the formula:

```
=A1 + B1
```

Cell `C1` would now have a value of `5`, and it would still have the formula as well. The result of a formula can not and will not change any cell's contents -- *it will only display a value*.

Cells are not variables and Excel is not a programming language.  You might be getting off of the wrong foot (or perhaps you should consider software designed for advanced mathematics like [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab).

**There are some great tutorials here:**

- [Excel Tutorials: 40 To Change Your Life](https://digital.com/blog/excel-tutorials/)

More of an answer would require more information like sample data and a little bit of background.  Check out [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code sitting behind the worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private vLastValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Target = Target.Value + vLastValue
        vLastValue = Target.Value
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        vLastValue = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This does mean you won't be able to delete the value in the cell - if you change the value by deleting it it will add 0 to the last value it held (and returning the value you just deleted).

You'll also get a type mismatch error if you try adding text.

There's probably 101 other things that could go wrong....

**Edit:**  Just saw those four little words in your question:  *while using excel solver.*
I've no idea if the code will work with solver.